# Integral of piecewise function

Tags: integration, measure-theory

We consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ with
$$f(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} 
          z & x=y \\
          2xyze^{-x^{2}}e^{-y^{2}}e^{-z^{2}} & \text{otherwise} \\
       \end{cases}$$
We want to show that the integral
$$\int_{[0,\infty)^3}fd\lambda$$
exists. Furthermore we want to calculate the integral.

I am not really interested in the specific exercise itself (I just posted it for better understanding and I want to try to solve it by myself) but how do you deal with the integral of such a piecewise defined function? Unfortunately, I didn't find any similar questions here since most questions regarding the integral of piecewise defined functions only involved subdomains which were defined by using intervalls. But I am really struggling with the integral of this function.

Comment: The set x=y having measure zero may be ignored. Just integrate the other part of the function, ignoring that it is piecewise.

Comment: Thank you! I suspect that the intervals of integrations also remain unchanged? So, we are just considering the integral $\int_{[0,\infty)^3} 2xyze^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}e^{-z^2}\text{dxdydz}$?

Comment: Not sure what "intervals of integration" refers to. But the integral of your comment is what I meant by simply integrating the "other choice" in the piecewise definition over $[0,\infty)^3.$

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to know. Thank you for your help!